# Prime numbers of the form $2357111317...$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $m_{n}$ be the number we get from putting first $n$ primes together.

$$m_{1}=2$$
$$m_{2}=23$$
$$m_{3}=235$$
$$m_{4}=2357$$
$$m_{5}=235711$$
$$m_{6}=23571113$$
$$m_{7}=2357111317$$

and so on. Only primes i found on this sequence with Mathematica are $m_{1}=2, m_{2}=23, m_{4}=2357.$ For $5\leq n\leq 40$ is composite. Are there any more primes of the form $m_{n}$?

Comment: Note that there is nothing specifically interesting about base $10$ in the context of this question (i.e., one could equally generate such sequence on any other base).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there are others.

From [the corresponding list in OEIS](https://oeis.org/A019518) we can find the [sublist of primes](https://oeis.org/A069151). Unfortunately, tough,

> The next term is the 355-digit number `2357111317192329313741434753...677683691701709719` which is too large to include here.

There other interesting lists linked there, like [this one](https://oeis.org/A046035), that is the list of "Numbers $n$ such that the concatenation of the first $n$ primes is a prime."

Answer (score 5):

These numbers are called [Smarandache–Wellin numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarandache%E2%80%93Wellin_number), and if they happen to be prime, they are called Smarandache–Wellin primes. There are many known primes of this form, and the first one after $2357$ is $m_{128}=235711\dots719$ (ending with prime $719$).

Answer (score 1):

The concatenation of the first $1,2,4,128,174,342,435,1429$ prime numbers are (probable) primes. And these are the only we know as of may 8th $2016$, M.Rodenkirch found no other primes up to the first $78498$ primes. Here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerSequencePrimes.html. These kind of primes has been called Smarandache-Wellin primes.